# How to replace blank lines to word?

Tags: notepad++

I have list

```
apple
oranges

banana
```

How to replace blank lines to word "empty"?

```
apple
oranges
empty
banana
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^$`
- Replace with: `empty`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       # beginning of line
$       # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

On replace dialog (Crtl+H) select "Extended". In "Find what" enter `\r\n\r\n`. In "Replace with" enter `\r\nempty\r\n`. And press "Replace", "Replace all" or whatever you need